# SharePoint 2013 Quick Edit Header Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, css

I am using Quick Edit view to add data in list. but when i entered more data like more than 10 or 15 then i can not see header of the column. so i need to scroll up the page and again scroll down to enter data. Is it possible to **add data from first row** in quick edit view or we can **fixed the header**.

Can anybody know ?

Comment: No you can't .. not without looking into custom JavaScript to manipulate the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s the code you should put on your pages:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://path to the script/StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js"></script>
```

You can download **StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js** from [here](http://spoodoo.com/downloads/)